# USB type-C ports max power supply from MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, power

What are the max power supplied by Apple's touch bar MacBook Pro from its USB type-C ports?

Answer (score 4):

[USB-C alone allows 4.5 Watts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB-C) ( 900 mA @ 5 V ) and thunderbolt 3 improves on that greatly.

According to Apple:

> MacBook Pro (15-inch, Late 2016) and MacBook (13-inch, Late 2016, Four
>   Thunderbolt 3 Ports) can power two devices that use up to 15 watts,
>   and two more devices that use up to 7.5 watts. It doesn't matter which
>   side of your MacBook Pro that they're connected to—power is delivered
>   on a first-come, first-served basis.
>
> MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2016, Two Thunderbolt 3 Ports) can power one
>   device that uses up to 15 watts and one device that uses up to 7.5
>   watts.

Thunderbolt Source: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207256
USB Source: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201163

The above specs are the same for the 2017 MacBook Pro models. The MacBook models only have USB levels of power and data available.

Comment: “USB-C alone allows 4.5 Watts”. This seems to imply that power delivery above 4.5 Watts is part of the Thunderbolt 3 spec and is not part of any USB specs. I think this is incorrect, as USB-PD defines power delivery schemes for up to 100 W. The question is which of those schemes the MacBook Pro etc support for power in and power out.

Comment: " The question is which of those schemes the MacBook Pro etc support for power in and power out. "  MacBook Pro laptops with USB-C ports support power in up to 100 W by USB-PD, and power out up to 15 W by USB 3.x.  USB-A ports will provide between 4.5 W and 12 W depending on the maximum power allowed by the USB spec in effect at the time the laptop was designed.  Power out on USB-A will be negotiated by USB 2.0 or USB 3.x.  I do not recall any evidence of Apple using USB-BC or USB-PD for power out on USB-A ports.